# How to toggle through 3 background colors using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a 4 in a row game. This means that I want that every time I click on a "circle" it changes color between default color ('grey'), player1 color ('blue') and player2 color ('red'). 
I am struggling with the toggling between 3 colors using jquery. The posts I have found are quite old and the code they suggested did not work for me.

Each "circle" is an HTML table element (ie table > tr > td repeated several times).

My js code looks like this:

```
$('tr > td').click(function () { 
if ($(this).css('background-color', 'grey' ) === true) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue' )
} else if ($(this).css('background-color', 'blue') === true) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red' )
}   else {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'grey' )
}
});
```

and my css stylesheet is:

```
td {
height: 90px;
width: 90px;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center; 
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
color:#fff;
font-size:1.1em;
font-weight:600;
background-color: grey;
border: 2px solid black;
}
```

When I click on each  nothing happens. Looking a bit more it seems that the first consition (ie if td bckgd color = grey) seems to be always false meaning the if function never starts. 
However I dont understand why this is the case. Am I writing the "if" condition wrong? (I tried with == instead of ===, doesnt work).

FYI I have also tried using .toggleClass() but this does not seem to work for a toggle between 3 colors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can place the colours you want to cycle through in an array. Then you can successively iterate through this array on click of each circle using an index value which can be stored in a `data` attribute on the `td`. You can also use the modulo operator to continue from the start when the end of the array is reached. Try this:

```js
var colours = ['grey', 'blue', 'red'];

$('tr > td').click(function() {
  var $cell = $(this);
  var index = $cell.data('index') || 0;
  $cell.css('background-color', colours[++index % colours.length]);
  $cell.data('index', index);
});
```

```css
td {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 600 1.1em;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

td {
height: 90px;
width: 90px;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center; 
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
color:#fff;
font-size:1.1em;
font-weight:600;
background-color: grey;
border: 2px solid black;
}

<script>
    var color = 0;
$('tr > td').click(function () { 
 $('td').each(function() {
  if(color == 0){
   $(this).css('background', 'gray');
   color = 1
  }
  else if(color == 1){
  $(this).css('background', 'red');
  color = 2
  }
  else{
  $(this).css('background', 'blue');
  color = 0
  }

  });
}); 
</script>
```